# Polymer and Playframework partial rendering navigation?

Tags: ajax, playframework, polymer, playframework-2.3

I am trying out Playframework with Polymer as a GUI tool. As a JSF developer, I am not really used to developing these ajax codes.

For now, I have this situation in my main.scala.html:

```
<core-scaffold>
    <core-header-panel navigation flex mode="seamed">
        <core-toolbar>Painel Administrativo</core-toolbar>
        <nav>
            <core-menu selected="0">
                <paper-item noink>
                    <a href="@routes.ProjetoController.listar()">
                        <core-icon icon="settings"></core-icon> Projetos
                    </a>
                </paper-item>
                <paper-item noink>
                    <a href="@routes.TipoProjetoController.listar()">
                        <core-icon icon="settings"></core-icon>Tipos de Projetos
                    </a>
                </paper-item>
            </core-menu>
        </nav>
    </core-header-panel>
    <div tool></div>
    <div fit>@content</div>
</core-scaffold>
```

**Question is:** Is there a way of calling the routes I have into the paper-item elements and partially render it into **@content** ?? If so, how could I achieve this one page style behavior, without the page resfresh?

PS.: these are not static content.

ProjetoController.listar() should render **projeto_listar.scala.html** and TipoProjetoController.listar() should render **tipoProjeto_listar.scala.html**. Those are 2 different dynamic pages which implments main:

```
@()

@main("Page Title") {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Page.JS](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAAahUKEwjBzva2yevGAhUCHpAKHWPxCfg&url=https%3A%2F%2Fvisionmedia.github.io%2Fpage.js%2F&ei=peOtVYHoJIK8wATj4qfADw&usg=AFQjCNGz5fUEShrZA-MtPmGp3C0H3LzsYg&sig2=TzwGWO-PIY6i5eIznso1Pw&bvm=bv.98197061,d.Y2I), you can make all the routes in the single page format.